# verify request before redirecting to static folder using express js

Tags: node.js, express, routes

I have a javascript app available under public folder but before users access the folder I would like to perform a verification on the request using express middleware.

Here's the project tree :

```
|__app.js
|__routes
   |__root.js
|__public
   |__css
   |__js
   |__fonts
   |__index.html
```

In app.js I have the code below :

```
var rootRoutes = require('./routes/root');
app.use("/", rootRoutes);
app.use("/",express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
```

And in routes/root.js I have the following method :

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

router.get('/*', function (req, res) {
    if( req.headers['x-mineqprovenance'] === "INTRANET"){
        //REDIRECT TO STATIC FOLDER 
    }
    else{
        res.send("PLEASE USE THE INTRANET NETWORK.");
    }
});

module.exports = router;
```

What should I do after the verification ?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should implement your header check as a middleware. Documentation on middleware can be [found here](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-middleware.html).

```
app.use(
    "/",
    function (req, res, next) {
        if( req.headers['x-mineqprovenance'] === "INTRANET"){
            next();
        } else {
            res.send("PLEASE USE THE INTRANET NETWORK.");
        }
    },
    express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public'))
);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Could you please give me more explanation on next() instruction ? I don't really get it...

Comment: The `next()` refers to the next item in the middleware chain and passes control of the request to the next item in the chain, which in my example is `express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public'))`.

Comment: I'm sorry to unmark this issue as resolved but I get NOT FOUND 404 error when I tried this solution...

Comment: I've tested this locally and it works for me. The only thing that I can think of being at issue is that the file you are attempting to access does not exist in the `public` folder. As a minor debugging step, you could add a log to the verification middleware (before you call `next()` or `res.send()`) to ensure you are hitting the route. Alternatively, try removing the verification middleware to see if the `express.static` section of your code works